# Tools for manipulating PowerPoint files

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

Do you know **managed tools** for manipulating PowerPoint files?

The tool should be 100% managed code and offer the option to
handle `.ppt` and `.pptx` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 100% managed could be going the hard route, however, you can use the [Office PIAs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=59DAEBAA-BED4-4282-A28C-B864D8BFA513) from your .NET code. Joel Spolsky has [an article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html) discussing your various options.